# Why is ActionBar not appearing? Nativescript/Angular2

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Why is my `ActionBar` not appearing on my `/home` page, when it's working on my `/login` page?

**login.component.html**

```
<ActionBar title="Application Title"></ActionBar>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<ActionBar title="Application Title"></ActionBar>
```

No error is thrown when this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that if you're creating a submodule within the `NativeScript/Angular2` application that you add this to your submodule's import statement:

```
import {NativeScriptModule} from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
```

In my case, `home.component.ts` and `home.component.html` was part of a submodule called `home.module.ts`.

```
import {NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import {HomeRoutingModule} from "./home-routing.module";
import {NativeScriptModule} from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HomeRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptModule //<-- this is needed
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class HomeModule {

}
```

[github nativescript issue #450](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/450)